# how to display a binary content of image/pdf in javascript?

Tags: javascript, parsing, binary-data

I have a binary content of image/pdf in java script variable downloaded from server.  There will be indication from server about the type of the file. I have to display the content in respective file format. If it is image , i have to display the image. If it is a pdf, i have to open the content in pdf format. and so on. How to parse the binary content and display it? I have searched for it. But I couldn't find exact solution. I'm using jquery mobile framework. Pls help..

Edit: Im developing mobile app. The server gives JSON response of binary content. How to make it display with javascript, since jquery mobile frame work, is based on java script.

Comment: This is almost as bad as the asker that wanted to write a PostScript engine in XSLT. But still pretty close.

Comment: Base64 encode it and link it as a [data uri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)? :p

Comment: I would say your best bet is PHP or some other server side language. It's really easy to do it with them.

Comment: If you are developing a mobile app, you can try putting a PDF file inside an `iframe` (or a `frame`). Some mobile browsers will display it. Some will just let user download the PDF. You also have Google Docs viewer if you want to embed a publicly available PDF files. It can generate iframe code for you.

Comment: @Thai I cant use google viewer, since it makes document publicly available. My problem is how to save the file and read(or parse) the file to display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a close to impossible task unless you are ready to implement a PDF parser in javascript which is not something I would dive into. You should avoid using AJAX to download files. Define proper `Content-Type` and `Content-Disposition` HTTP headers on the server and leave the client display it by providing a normal link to the file.

Comment: @Ka-rocks, modify your logic so that it isn't the client (javascript) which fetches this data from the server but make a server side script which acts as a client to fetch the data from the remote web service and stream it into the response. This way all that is left on the client is to provide a link to this bridge script.

Comment: The client makes a ajax call to a web service hosted in a server. The web service gives response with a binary data enclosed in a JSON format. But file type will be specified in the response. My problem is how to display that binary data into image/pdf/doc.

Comment: @Ka-rocks, I understand what you are doing but the problem is that once you fetch this binary data with javascript there's not much you could do with it. That's why I suggested you to move this logic into a server side script.